# SIM card communication protocol

Tags: stm32, protocol

My board contains an STM32 (manual [here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/REFERENCE_MANUAL/CD00225773.pdf)) and a SIM card reader (manual [here](http://www.icbase.com/pdf/ONS/ONS23860605.pdf)). I need to write drivers to test that the SIM reader is working an properly communicating with the STM32. However, looking through both manuals, I couldn't find a way to get the two devices to "talk" to each other.

Is there a standard SIM card communication protocol for embedded devices? How can I do basic I/O on a SIM card?

Comment: Actually, I realise that the chapter "Smartcard" under USART covers what I want, although at no point is "SIM" mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smart cards come in several flavours, each with their own protocols. Here's some Arduino code to read ISO7816 T=0 cards:

http://www.makomk.com/~aidan/iso7816_interface.pde

Here's an overview of the standard:

http://www.smartcardsupply.com/Content/Cards/7816standard.htm

Comment: I love standards, but I just couldn't like the Arduino :)

Comment: The Arduino is just another microcontroller dev board. It's programmable in C with GNU tools, "what's not to like?"

Comment: There is nothing wrong or different with its hardware, however the software just bugs me, I do not feel in the control of the things. And I just hate the modules! I own an Arduino by the way :)

Comment: Quick question. What is the difference between `.pde` and `.c` files?

Comment: A .pde file is an Arduino sketch. A sketch is C++ to which the IDE automatically adds a header and footer to provide main() and initialisation code.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the official ETSI specification [here](http://www.etsi.org/WebSite/Standards/Standard.aspx) (Downloads).

The particular specification that is interesting for you is
**ETSI TS 102 221**
"Smart Cards; UICC-Terminal interface; Physical and logical characteristics"

Although the spec mentions both protocols "T=0" and "T=1" it is very likely that you only need "T=0" if you use only SIM cards (no banking cards etc.).